# how get 5 random number from a range which from 0 to 100?

Tags: ruby, random, range

I want to generate 5 different random numbers. I have generated a range from 0 to 100. I want to pick 5 numbers from the range randomly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate a list of n unique random numbers in Ruby like this:

```
(1..99).to_a.sample(5)
=>[69, 50, 15, 68, 29]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = []
while true
   a << rand(101) # if you want to get 100
   break if a.uniq.count == 5
end
```

it can get 5 different random number.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try something like this:

```
arr = []
(1..5).each{|t| arr << rand(100)}
arr
#=> [78, 19, 34, 96, 59]
```

This array may contain repeated elements as pointed out by @p11y in comments.

Here's the fix to that (inspired by his comments):

```
a = 5.times.map { rand(100) }
until a.uniq.size==5 do
 a += (5-a.uniq.size).times.map{rand (100)}
end 
a.uniq!
```

I think there are better solutions already posted here, this is just an alternative answer.

Comment: This can produce the same number twice, the OP asked for "5 different random numbers".

Comment: Also, you could just write `5.times.map { rand(100) }`

Comment: @p11y thanks for teaching me  that. I have updated my answer. Though its still not elegant, I guess it should work fine now. scottxu's solution is much better.

Comment: +1 to this solution for taking the `5.times.map { rand(100) }` idea and finding an interesting way to make sure the results are unique.